# Document filter is not working in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

In text field more than 10 characters na, it has to show an error. For that i used document filter:

```
JTextField field = (JTextField) txtFld;
AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) field.getDocument();
document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter(10));
```

So this is my document filter coding. I registered the textfield through document filter. But nothing has happening here. How to use document filter?

DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter class which has the error msg.

Comment: None of your previous 8 questions had any acceptable answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing the code for `DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter` I would suspect that you havn't implemented (/override) the [`DocumentFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)'s [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html#replace%28javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29) method:

```
@Override
public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                    int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
        throws BadLocationException {

    ....
}
```

---

Screenshot from the code below:

[image: screenshot]

---

### Example implementation of `DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter`:

```
static class DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    private final int max;

    public DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                             String text, AttributeSet attr) 
            throws BadLocationException {
        if (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() < max)
            super.insertString(fb, offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
        else 
            showError();
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                        int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
            throws BadLocationException {
        int documentLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
        if (documentLength - length + text.length() < max)
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
        else 
            showError();
    }

    private void showError() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too many characters entered");
    }
}
```

### Example `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
    AbstractDocument d = (AbstractDocument) firstName.getDocument();
    d.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentSizeAndUppercaseFilter(10));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(firstName);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 60);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried my example. Doesn't it work as you want it to work?

Comment: Should work (works for me)! Rewrote example to match your needs. *Now displays an error message when too many characters are inserted.* (also added a screenshot)

Comment: +1 works for me, too, although I had to import the right `AttributeSet`. :-)

Comment: Sorry.I had done mistake..Now its working properly..thanks a lot

Comment: Informative answer, it also works in my code, thanks for guiding.

Answer (score 1):

Start with something simple.

The section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) has a working example that does half of what you want.