# Change Input Limit Class into a Function

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, user-input

I have a basic class which allows me to limit the number of characters entered in the JTextField (or any field for that matter), but I am wondering if there is a way to convert the class into a function so I can put the function in my "Utilities" class, with my other helper functions. It would be ideal if I can give the limit as a parameter to the function.

Currently it is called like this:

```
textfield.setDocument(new InputLimit());
```

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
textfield.setDocument(Utilities.setInputLimit(10));
```

My class is as follows:

```
public class InputLimit extends PlainDocument {

    private final int charLimit = 10;

    InputLimit() {
        super();
    }

    public void insertString(int offset, String str,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (str == null) {
            return;
        }

        if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= charLimit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to create a `static` method? With what signature?

Comment: Use a DocumentFilter instead of PlainDocument, the method you have demonstrated has been out-of-Date for more then 10 years

Comment: Yes, I want to create a static method, but not sure what you mean by signature. @MadProgrammer, do I need to implement both insertString and replace methods of DocumentFilter and would I need to case the JTextfield as an AbstractDocument first, like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527323/?

Comment: Check out [these examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `charLimit` as a *constructor* argument as

```
textfield.setDocument(new InputLimit(10));
```

Just add the following constructors in your class

```
public class InputLimit extends PlainDocument {

    private final int charLimit = 10;

    // Keep this if you want a no-arg constructor too
    InputLimit() { super(); }

    // compiler will auto add the super() call for you
    public InputLimit(int limit) { this.charLimit = limit; }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
private final int charLimit = 10;

InputLimit() { super(); }
```

To:

```
private final int charLimit = 10;

InputLimit(int charLimit) { 
    super(); 
    this.charLimit = charLimit;
}
```

To create one:

```
textfield.setDocument(new InputLimit(15));
```

Comment: This only helps with the parameter (which I appreciate), but still does not help me make the code into a function, instead of a Class.

Comment: To create one: `textfield.setDocument(new InputLimit(15));`..  This does not need a method.